# Change value within cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, string

As you can see, in this **pandas dataframe** there are some names which start with " [' " and end with " ' "

How can I do for removing all of these from the entire column?

Thanks a lot !

```
Full_Name                              
0       ['Raya'   
1        ['Valentin'   
2    ['Virginie'   
3           ['Alice'   
4        ['Nicolas'    
5  ['Alexandre'    
6     ['Guillaume'    
7       ['Laura'
```